# Selecting an object from a listbox quickly

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve an object that is in an array when the user selects something in the listbox.

At the moment the listbox has a list of filenames and the way I have achieved the solution is by looping through the array and finding a matching filename and using the object reference once it has been found.

```
foreach (CPSImage img in objWholeLibrary)
        {
            if (Path.GetFileName(img.FileName).Equals(lbxImageObjects.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                currImage = img;
                break;
            }
        }
        UpdateDisplay();
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Instead of relying on a string to match to the object?

Comment: Is this WPF, WinForms, or web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET Framework version at least 3.5 then you can do it with LINQ:

```
currImage = objWholeLibrary.FirstOrDefault(
    img => Path.GetFileName(img.FileName).Equals(
        lbxImageObjects.SelectedItem.ToString())
    );
UpdateDisplay();
```

Execution speed should be the same, just the code will look a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading the items into the listbox?  You might be better off loading the array object into the listbox and then overriding the ToString() method to provide the string you are looking for in the listbox.

So for example, if my list box is populated with people, I could do this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    { 
        Person p = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()};
        listBox1.Items.Add(p);
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Person)listBox1.SelectedItem).ID);
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return LastName + ", " + FirstName + " - " + ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this;

```
currImage = objWholeLibrary.Single(img => Path.GetFileName(img.FileName).Equals(lbxImageObjects.SelectedItem.ToString()));

UpdateDisplay();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the listbox is populated with all the array's items then you only have to get the selected index of the listbox and get the element at the same index in the array, they should match since the list and the array have the same data and the same indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you fill your collections, but you can use Tag property of ListBoxItem to store image reference. After select just cast Tag value to your object.